# Connection timeout Error while connecting to facebook through node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook

I'm trying with this code. It is loading for sometime then producing connection timeout error. Is there any proxy to be set? If so how to set those proxy?

```
var https = require('https');

exports.getFbData = function(accessToken, apiPath, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: 'graph.facebook.com',
        port: 443,
        path: apiPath + '?access_token=' + accessToken, //apiPath example: '/me/friends'
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var buffer = ''; //this buffer will be populated with the chunks of the data received from facebook
    var request = https.get(options, function(result){
        result.setEncoding('utf8');
        result.on('data', function(chunk){
            buffer += chunk;
        });
        result.on('end', function(){
            callback(buffer);
        });
    });
    request.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('error from facebook.getFbData: ' + e.message)
    });
   request.end();
}
```

Thanks in advance.